# VS code tracking a function doesn't work with Laravel Facade

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-facade

I really like `Laravel Facade` when transforming dynamic class to static.
For instance, I can easily add the keyword `Facades` and call it a static class.

```php
    use Facades\App\Services\MyService;
    public function something() {
        $something = MyService::getSomething();
    }
```

Normally we can track `getSomething()` function using `Ctrl+click` in VS code editor.
But with `Facades`, `Ctrl+click` doesn't work.

Any workaround with this to make the `getSomething` function trackable?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this package on GitHub https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

I have used this for a number of years with various IDEs.

You may need this extension for VSCode https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgykurian.laravel-ide-helper

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

> Laravel Extension Pack

In my work.I use Ctrl+T to search for function which not automatic linked